# List subclasses in Sphinx using autodoc

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

Is there an autodoc-directive that will list all subclasses of a given class?

If I have the following Python-Code:

```
class Base(object):
    pass

class A(Base):
    pass

class B(Base):
    pass
```

Is there a way to generate an Output like:

```
Classes implementing Base: A, B
```

Using Sphinx, Autodoc and Re-Structured text. (Like :show-inheritance: but backwards). Something like:

```
.. autoclass:: Base
    :THE-COMMAND-I-AM-MISSING:
```